# Integer overflow vulnerabilities in ASP.NET Core applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integer-overflow

I have the following controller method in my application:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllBooksAsync([FromQuery] string pageNo, string itemsPerPage)
{
    int intSkip = int.TryParse(pageNo, out int _skip) ? _skip : 0;
    int intTake = int.TryParse(itemsPerPage, out int _take) ? _take : 0;

    // Calling the repository method.
    var result = await _repo.GetAllBooksAsync(intSkip * intTake, intTake);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

And my repository method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> GetAllBooksAsync(int skip = 0, int take = 0)
{
    var query = _ctx.Books
                        .Skip(skip);
    if(take < 1)
    {
        return await query
                        .ToListAsync();
    }

    return await query
                     .Take(take)
                     .ToListAsync();
}
```

When calling the repository method, I pass the number of entries to skip by simply multiplying the intSkip variable by intTake variable. If large enough values are provided through the query string parameters, can this multiplication step cause an integer overflow?

Comment: Yes. Quite clearly. Whether that's a vulnerability -- well, in your code, it just means that you return everything. Do you want to be able to return all books? That sounds like an easy way to DOS your API. But, you don't stop someone from requesting `int.MaxValue` items either

Comment: You'd probably want to simply clamp  `take` to eg. 0 to 100.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a vulnerability, it is a matter of your implementation. First of all, I would like to say that pagination can be a source of performance problems and you should carefully consider its implementation if your database contains even thousands of items.

So at least you can set a reasonable maximum number of pages to skip. Also, your `pageNo` and `itemsPerPage` could be easily made `int`, and you can use some [validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to check if they follow your rules. For example, [RangeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-7.0). This way you avoid parsing the string into an integer and get rid of some of the logic associated with it in your controller.

Also, this line of code can also cause integer overflow:

```
var result = await _repo.GetAllBooksAsync(intSkip * intTake, intTake);
```

The problem is in multiplying these parameters `intSkip * intTake`.

And please take a look at this code:

```
if(take < 1)
{
    return await query
             .ToListAsync();
}
```

There is an obvious performance issue. For example, if `take = 0`, it will return all books from the database. This can be a little painful for your users and for the system as a whole.